# Modified List Box throws Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I modified Listbox mentioned in my[Change the Selected Color Listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519845/change-the-selected-color-listbox) question and when ever i select item exception is thrown.It reads

```
'{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for property 'Background'.
```

What am i doing wrong

Usage XMAL

```
   <ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}"  Width="300" Height="519" Name="listFriends" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
     <ListBox.Items>
       <StackPanel Width="289" Orientation="Horizontal"  >
         <Image Margin="0,0,4,0" Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding Picture}" />
         <my:RibbonCheckBox Label="test" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
       </StackPanel>
       <StackPanel Width="289" Orientation="Horizontal"  >
          <Image Margin="0,0,4,0" Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding Picture}" />
          <my:RibbonCheckBox Height="20" Label="test" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Foreground="White" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="289" Orientation="Horizontal"  >
           <Image Margin="0,0,4,0" Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding Picture}" />
           <my:RibbonCheckBox Height="20" Label="test" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Foreground="White" />
        </StackPanel>
     </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

Style I have Modified

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="10"
        >
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource GrBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource GradientBrush}"/>
                       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>                        
            </ControlTemplate>                    
        </Setter.Value>                
    </Setter>            
</Style>
```

Comment: Can you post the complete XAML snippet? It looks like your binding is producing unexpected results.

Comment: this looks fine assuming GrBrush and Gradient brush are legit.  are you 100% sure the problem is coming from this snippet of your XAML and that you have no code interacting with the Background property?

Comment: yes i am sure when i removed this snipit it works fine

Comment: Can you show me the declaration of the GradientBrush XAML, including the location that it is declared? (e.g. UserControl.Resources, ListBox.Resources, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that i declared

```
 <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GrBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6BB9E8" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#541882CE" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
```

used like

```
<Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource GradientBrush}"/>
```

with GrBrush and usage was different that is why error occured