# Override WindowsTheme colors for Listbox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, listbox, windows-themes

I have a listbox that has a custom selected item color as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138200/change-background-color-for-selected-listbox-item).  It works great so long as I'm using the Windows 7 theme.  If I use the windows classic theme, the background color is dark blue, which makes the black text illegible.

Is there any way to override the default colors associated with a windows theme?  The colors that we're using in our app are driven from our monochromatic palette and shouldn't be affected by any specific theme.

Example:

[image]

VS

[image]

Comment: You can change the ListBoxItemTemplate and modify the selected foreground color as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475216/how-to-customize-the-color-of-the-currently-selected-item-of-a-listbox/13475904#13475904